# scrollable legend mpandroidchart piechart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented a `piechart` with help of the `mpandroid library`:

[image]

as you can see everything works fine... but I have a small problem with
my pie chart legend on the right side.

The highness of the page is to small. The legend is not displayed completly.

My legend code:

```
Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
l.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);
l.setXEntrySpace(7);
l.setYEntrySpace(5);
setContentView(mChart);
```

Is there an option to increase the high of the chart automaticaly so the legend is displayed completly or at least a scroll functionality?

Thx in advance

Stefan

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. I am able to show a scrollable legend using recycler view but unable to get the color code reference for each legend. Have you cracked through this? If yes please post your answer.